# How to tell CMake to name Visual Studio INSTALL-projects uniquely?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cmake

I am using CMake to create Visual C++ 2010 projects like this:

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"

mkdir build
mkdir build\VisualStudio2010

cd build\VisualStudio2010
cmake -G"Visual Studio 10" ..\..
```

This creates four projects:

- `ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`
- `MyProject.vcxproj`
- `INSTALL.vcxproj`
- `ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj`

Now I often do need to put multiple `INSTALL`-projects into *one* Visual Studio solution. This only works if I name those `INSTALL`-projects uniquely, e.g. `MyProject-INSTALL.vcxproj`. However, doing this manually for each project after running CMake isn't very brilliant.

Is there a way to tell CMake, what file name to use for the created INSTALL-projects, e.g. to prefix them with the project name? I searched the docs and asked Google, but found no solution.